# Complex trinomial factoring $ 2 \cos x - 2 = \sin^2 x$

Tags: factoring, trigonometry

$2 \cos x -2 = \sin^2 x$

I have been trying to solve this equation for the interval $0 \le x \le 2\pi$ .

I figured I should keep them as one, so I put

$2 \cos x -2 = 1 - \cos^{2} x$

however I don't really know how to proceed from there, and i'm pretty sure i'm not actually solving it correctly. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE.  __2__ things: I have reformatted your post  but the input interpretation may be wrong so in future use
 [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $LaTeX$ and secondly, 
if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. All the best.

Comment: Let $t=\cos x$, then you have quadratic in $t$: $t^2+2t-3=0.$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$$2\cos(x)-2=\sin^2(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-2+2\cos(x)-\sin^2(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-3+2\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(\cos(x)-1)(3+\cos(x))=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(x)-1=0\Longleftrightarrow \space\space\vee\space\space 3+\cos(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(x)=1\Longleftrightarrow \space\space\vee\space\space \cos(x)=-3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=2\pi n_1 \space\space\vee\space\space x=\pm\cos^{-1}(-3)+2\pi n_2$$

With $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $\cos(x) \neq -3$, as $-1 \leq \cos(x) \leq 1 \forall x$.

Comment: I say it is a hint....!

Comment: While you are right in that there are complex solutions to this problem, I'm assuming the OP is only looking for real solutions, as any class where this would be a standard problem isn't going to be messing with complex numbers (at least in my experience). Further, your use of logic symbols is correct, but is likely to confusing someone just starting with trig equations. You also give a general solution, when the problem clearly gives a restricted domain... Providing a general solution isn't a hint in my book.

Comment: Thanks, maybe it is good to look after that thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

$$2 \cos x -2 = \sin^2x$$
$$\Rightarrow 2 \cos x -2 = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow 4 \cos x -4 = 1-\cos(2x)$$
$$\Rightarrow 4 \cos x +\cos(2x) = 5$$
We then note that the $\cos x$ has a range of $[0,1]$, and thus our equation is only equal to $5$ when $\cos(2x) = 1$ and $\cos x = 1$. These both happen at interval of $2\pi$ (think of the unit circle here... only when it is $0$ degrees), and so our answer is $x = 2\pi n$, where $n$ is any integer. We have restricted our domain though from $0$ to $2\pi$, so the answer is $x=0,2\pi$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: collect terms and treat the result as a quadratic equation where the variable is $\cos x$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

For $$ 2 \cos x - 2 = \sin^2 x$$

Note that $$\sin^2 x = {1-\cos^2x}$$
$$\implies2 \cos x - 2 = {1-\cos^2x}$$

Now solve the quadratic in disguise by letting $u=\cos x$